# XNA Framework - Trying to correctly overload System.EventHandler<Platformer.PlayerIndexEventArgs>

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am new to C# and XNA.  I am currently working on the Options Menu for a game.  The Options Menu does the following:

1. Sound (on or off)
2. Brightness (Increase/Decrease)
3. Scoreboard (View 5 Highest scores)
4. Controls (shows how to use the controls)

I found some code on the internet that handles the Brightness but it was implemented using the Game.cs class.  I am trying to use that code in my OptionsMenuScreen.cs class (which inherits from Gamescreen.cs).

The problem I am having is that my EventHandler called BrightnessSelected is overloaded with some extra parameters to handle the the touch input so that the user can brighten/darken the screen.  This overloading is causing some problems because its based on the template provided in System.EventHandler, which only takes one parameter.

How can I get that template to allow me to overload it?  Or is there another ay to do this?  I really hope that this makes sense and that I have conveyed my problem in a non-convoluted way.  Thanks to all of you!

Code is below:

```
#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
#endregion

namespace Platformer
{
/// <summary>
/// The options screen is brought up over the top of the main menu
/// screen, and gives the user a chance to configure the game
/// in various hopefully useful ways.
/// </summary>
class OptionsMenuScreen : MenuScreen
{

    #region Fields
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D whiteTexture;
    int brightnessStart;
    int contrastStart;
    BlendState brightnessBlend;
    BlendState contrastBlend;

    MenuEntry sound1;
    MenuEntry brightness;
    MenuEntry scoreboard;
    MenuEntry controls;

    static bool soundonoff = true;

    #endregion

    #region Initialization

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public OptionsMenuScreen()
        : base("Options")
    {
        // Create our menu entries.
        sound1 = new MenuEntry(string.Empty);
        brightness = new MenuEntry(string.Empty);
        scoreboard = new MenuEntry(string.Empty);
        controls = new MenuEntry(string.Empty);

        SetMenuEntryText();

        // Hook up menu event handlers.
        brightness.Selected += brightnessSelected;
        sound1.Selected += sound1Selected;
        scoreboard.Selected += scoreboardSelected;
        controls.Selected += controlsSelected;

        // Add entries to the menu.
        MenuEntries.Add(sound1);
        MenuEntries.Add(brightness);
        MenuEntries.Add(controls);
        MenuEntries.Add(scoreboard);
    }

    protected void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here


        brightnessStart = 255;
        contrastStart = 128;

        brightnessBlend = new BlendState();
        brightnessBlend.ColorSourceBlend = brightnessBlend.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.Zero;
        brightnessBlend.ColorDestinationBlend = brightnessBlend.AlphaDestinationBlend            
        = Blend.SourceColor;

        contrastBlend = new BlendState();
        contrastBlend.ColorSourceBlend = contrastBlend.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.DestinationColor;
        contrastBlend.ColorDestinationBlend = contrastBlend.AlphaDestinationBlend = `Blend.SourceColor;`
    }

    public virtual void LoadContent()
    {
        whiteTexture = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice, 1, 1);
        whiteTexture.SetData<Color>(new Color[] { Color.White });
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphicsDevice);
    }

    public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, brightnessBlend);
        spriteBatch.Draw(whiteTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, 480, 800), new Color(brightnessStart, `brightnessStart, brightnessStart, 255));`
        spriteBatch.End();

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, contrastBlend);
        spriteBatch.Draw(whiteTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, 480, 800), new Color(contrastStart, `contrastStart, contrastStart, 255));`
        spriteBatch.End();

        graphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills in the latest values for the options screen menu text.
    /// </summary>
    void SetMenuEntryText()
    {
        sound1.Text = "Sound " + (soundonoff ? "on" : "off");
        brightness.Text = "Brightness ";
        scoreboard.Text = "Scoreboard ";
        controls.Text = "Controls ";
    }

    #endregion

    #region Handle Input

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for when the Sound menu entry is selected.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    protected void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        foreach (TouchLocation t in TouchPanel.GetState())
        {
            if ((t.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
                    || (t.State == TouchLocationState.Moved))
            {
                if (t.Position.Y <= 400)
                    brightnessSelected(t, ref brightnessStart);
            }
            else
                brightnessSelected(t, ref contrastStart);
        }
    }
    void sound1Selected(object sender, PlayerIndexEventArgs e)
    {
        soundonoff = !soundonoff;
        SetMenuEntryText();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for when the Brightness menu entry is selected.
    /// </summary>
    void brightnessSelected(object sender, PlayerIndexEventArgs e, TouchLocation t, ref int adjustee)
    {
        if (t.Position.X < 240)
            adjustee -= 3;
        else
            adjustee += 3;

        adjustee = Math.Max(Math.Min(adjustee, 255), 0);
        SetMenuEntryText();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for when the Scoreboard menu entry is selected.
    /// </summary>
    void scoreboardSelected(object sender, PlayerIndexEventArgs e)
    {
        //need to find a way to transition to HighScoreScreen.cs here
        //ScreenManager.AddScreen(new HighScoreScreen(), e.PlayerIndex);
        SetMenuEntryText();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for when the Control menu entry is selected.
    /// </summary>
    void controlsSelected(object sender, PlayerIndexEventArgs e)
    {
        //ScreenManager.AddScreen(new ControlScreen(), e.PlayerIndex);
        SetMenuEntryText();
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

Comment: Please shorten your code to the important parts. Most people will not look through your code looking for the method you are refering to.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass `ref int adjustee` to the event handler and expect it's value to be returned to the callee. Event handlers just don't work that way. Think of it more as a callback that can respond to an event.

Next, you need to subclass EventArgs and add your own data to it, like this.

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string msg;

    public MyEventArgs( string messageData ) 
    {
        msg = messageData;
    }
    public string Message { 
        get { return msg; } 
        set { msg = value; }
    }
}
```

See this article about handlers and args: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx

In your case, you need to visit the code for `MenuEntry` and edit the `TEventArgs` type that it is passing (in this case it is using `PlayerIndexEventArgs`). You could subclass `PlayerIndexEventArgs` again, or just redefine it to your own type. I don't know what that XNA class is and you may need to think about the design again if it doesn't make sense.

When you are done, you should have something like

```
int _brightness;

void brightnessSelectedEventHandler(object sender, BrightnessEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.touch != null && e.touch.position != null)
    {
        const int TOUCH_POS_THRESHOLD = 240; // this is part of UI and should really be somewhere else, but put it here for convenience
        if (e.touch.position.x < TOUCH_POS_THRESHOLD 
            adjustBrightness(-3);
        else
            adjustBrightness(3);
    }
    SetMenuEntryText();
}

void adjustBrightness(int offset)
{
    _brightness += offset;
}
```

Note that here I just put a member variable _brightness in your class. That is how you "respond" to an event - put some data somewhere or adjust a value. You need to think about where the data lives and where it should be encapsulated from an OO perspective.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Let me read up on handlers and args.  I appreciate the help.